# Javascript save binary data to file with ANSI encoding

Tags: javascript, file-io, character-encoding

I am trying to save a binary string to file using [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). I am specifying the charset as ANSI but the file has the UTF-8 encoding.

```
var blob = new Blob([bin], {type: "octet/stream;charset=ANSI"});
saveAs(blob, "binfile.dat");
```

Is there a way to save the file as ANSI?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure bin is ANSI data?
I had the same problem where I wanted to download a zip file from the server. It turns out that I had to specify in the header of my request what response I wanted. Here's my code sample in Angular downloading a zip file but it will be the same concept no matter how you make your http request:

```
$http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
```

Then you can create the Blob and save it:

```
var blob = new Blob([bin], { type: "application/zip", responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
saveAs(blob, "binfile.zip");
```

Comment: Thank you! I had an issue with the encoding. The file downloaded was always encoded as UTF-8, messing up with it. It solved the problem.